# Javascript user input validation

Tags: javascript

My exercise is to force a user to type a number and check that it is less than 100.  I think I've done this well but there is another case I don't know how to do.  If the user does not type any number in the space, the program should show something like "you must type a number".  How should I write the code?

```
var number=prompt('enter a number');
if (number<100){
    newnumber=100-number;
    document.write(number+'is less than 100 by'+ newnumber);
}else if(number>100){
    document.write('type again');
}
```

Comment: i think using prompt you cannot do this.

Comment: @Mahi Of course you can...

Comment: @Brad how can you disable prompt for returning  empty string value ?

Comment: @Mahi You re-show the prompt.

Comment: @Brad that's a good idea :D

Answer (score 2):

You can determine if the users input is a valid number by using the [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function.  I have also validated the blank character for you, as shown below.

```
var isValid = !isNaN(number) && number !== "";
```

**Full snippet:**

```js
var number = prompt('enter a number');
number = number.replace(/\s/g, ""); 
var isValid = !isNaN(number) && number !== "";

if (isValid) {
  if (number<100) {
     newnumber=100-number;
     document.write(number+'is less than 100 by'+ newnumber);
  } else if(number>100) {
      document.write('type again');
  }
} else {
   document.write("Looks like you didn't enter a valid number");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ezgn5cv5/

Comment: when i click ok after  typing nothing it shouldn't go to if condition

Comment: @Darren Davies i think you should remove spaces to avoid extra spaces also empty inputs `""` will be `0`

Comment: @MamdouhFreelancer - then you can add another check `&& number !== ""` - please see my update.

Comment: @DarrenDavies try to input multi space it will be 0 and outputs `is less than 100 by100`

Answer (score 1):

- Remove all spaces `.replace(/\s/g, "")`.
- Detect if user input a number using `parseFloat()` if you want to allow
  user to input decimal numbers like `5.254` or only integers using
  `parseInt()` like `5`.
- Then detect if `number > 100` or `number < 100`.

See this example:

```js
var number = prompt('enter a number');
    number = number.replace(/\s/g, ""); //remove all spaces

if (number != "") { // if not empty
  if (parseFloat(number) == number) { // if decimal/integer number
    if (number < 100) {
      newnumber = 100 - number;
      document.write(number + ' is less than 100 by ' + newnumber);
    } else if (number > 100) {
      //number = prompt('enter a number');
      document.write('type again');
    }
  } else {
      //number = prompt('enter a number');
    document.write('you must type a number');
  }
} else {  // if empty input
      //number = prompt('enter a number');
  document.write('shouldn\'t be empty');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var number = null;
while (number !== 0 && !number || number >= 100) {
  number = parseInt(prompt('Enter a number, less than 100'));
}

document.write(
  number + 
  ' is less than 100 by ' + 
  (100 - number)
);
```

This puts us in a loop for whether or not the number is a valid *integer* (I assumed that's what you wanted, but you could change this to float or something else), and under 100.  Only when the user's input is valid will it go to the line to output.

The **second** condition for the `while` loop is `!number`.  This basically tests for falsy conditions, such as `NaN` or `null`.  If `parseInt()` can't figure out what the user typed in for a number, it will return `NaN`.  And, of course, we initialized the `number` variable to `null`.

The **first** condition for `while` is `number !== 0` is actually required because of the second condition which tests for falsy.  `0` is falsy, but `0` is a valid number less than 100, so we need to make sure that we let `0` be valid.  Conditionals like these short circuit.  That means that they are processed from left to right, and any condition failing the test will immediately bypass the conditional block of code below.  If `number` is `0`, we know that the whole condition is false and we can move on.

The **third** condition simply ensures we're under `100` by re-prompting if we're not.

Also, I should note that `document.write()` has some issues.  It's better to select an element on the page and set its text.